# Can't run a migration adding userstamp to an existing table Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the gem blamer to add a userstamp into some tables that are already created. I tried to add userstamps while creating a new table and it worked.But I need to add to existing tables and I don't know what to write in the migration. This gem is like others that add userstamp but only this one seems working in rails 6.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  cattr_accessor :current_user
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_userstamp

  def set_userstamp
    User.current_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  end
end
```

```
class AddUserstampsToIllustrators < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_column :illustrators, :userstamps
  end
end
```

I got the following error:

```
== 20201106193035 AddUserstampsToIllustrators: migrating ======================
-- add_column(:illustrators, :userstamps)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 3)
/home/morganaborges/code/MorganaTBorges/bamboleio_project/db/migrate/20201106193035_add_userstamps_to_illustrators.rb:3:in `change'
/home/morganaborges/code/MorganaTBorges/bamboleio_project/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/morganaborges/code/MorganaTBorges/bamboleio_project/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
./bin/rails:3:in `load'
./bin/rails:3:in `<main>'

Caused by:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 3)
/home/morganaborges/code/MorganaTBorges/bamboleio_project/db/migrate/20201106193035_add_userstamps_to_illustrators.rb:3:in `change'
/home/morganaborges/code/MorganaTBorges/bamboleio_project/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/morganaborges/code/MorganaTBorges/bamboleio_project/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
./bin/rails:3:in `load'
./bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: You need add a type of column in your migration. You set only table, and fieldname.

Comment: yeah, but I know what type is :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at https://github.com/infused/blamer , by default the two columns are created_by and updated_by with type integer. So...

```
add_column :illustrators, :created_by, :integer
add_column :illustrators, :updated_by, :integer
```

(integer being used in https://github.com/infused/blamer/blob/master/lib/blamer/userstamp.rb#L47 )

Answer (score 0):

`ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 3)` you pass two arguments but you need to pass column type as the third argument. [Here is the documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_column) with a list of types.

```
add_column :illustrators, :userstamps, :string
# or
add_column :illustrators, :userstamps, :datetime
# etc.
```

Take a look at [the examples section](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_column-label-Examples).